# Swift - Get user email from Facebook out of GraphRequest

Tags: ios, swift, string, facebook, variables

Hi everyone I'm working with the Facebook login. In my app I need to take the Facebook user's email and insert it in a variable that can be reused but I'm having problems with this because the result of the request with `GraphRequest` is not visible outside this call

`GraphRequest(graphPath: _, parameters: _, tokenString: _, version : _, httpMethod: _)`

es.

```
   let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email"], tokenString: authToken, version: nil, httpMethod: HTTPMethod(rawValue: "GET"))
   request.start { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil { print(error!)}

        else {

             if let result = result as? [String:String], 
                let email: String = result["email"] {

                // "email" is not readable outside this function .. 
                // "email" outside this function is always nil
             }
           }
         }
```

how can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all, make sure that you have [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) to get the user *email*.

2) Then you can save it into `UserDefaults` or `Keychain` yo use it further on your demand.

---

Here is `Keychain` [wrapper](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) that you can use for simplification

Also for `UserDefaults` way:

```
let email: String = result["email"] {
 UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "userEmail") 
}

//...
let email = UserDefaults.standarts.string(forKey: "userEmail")
```

But be careful email it's sensitive data and a lot of developers recommending to save it into `Keychain` than into `UserDefaults`.

Comment: thanks!.. I had already thought about using the Keychain (KeychainSwift) ... in fact I think it's the best thing